# Get column names from query(not from table)

Tags: oracle

Is there any approach similar to Java's [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) for fetching column names from query? Please note that querying `User_Tab_Columns` cannot help me when I face some query like

```
Select 'Bruce' as "First_Name", 'Thomas' as "Middle_Name", 'Wayne' as "Last_Name"
From Dual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could make use of `dbms_sql.describe_columns`. This answer uses an extract of the code borrowed from [**here**](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536889800346305468)

If you wish you may convert this to a  `TABLE` function which returns the column names for any given query to simplify things for you. I'll leave that as an exercise for you !

```
declare
    p_query varchar2(32767) := 
              q'{
                  Select 'Bruce'   as "First_Name", 'Thomas' 
                      as "Middle_Name", 'Wayne' as "Last_Name"
                   From Dual
                 }';
    l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    l_colCnt        number;

begin

    dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  p_query, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );

        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
            dbms_output.put_line(  l_descTbl(i).col_name );
        end loop;

end;
/
```

**Output**

```
First_Name
Middle_Name
Last_Name


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5cb35f804510bf9b5666de291e6a693)